# Why is it useful to use dS in the formula for arc length?

Tags: calculus, notation, polar-coordinates, parametric, arc-length

When discussing finding the arc length of some curve $C$ defined by parametric equations $x = f(\theta)$, $y = g(\theta)$, my professor said the following:

> Given $f', g'$ are continuous on $[\alpha, \beta]$ and $C$ is traversed exactly once as $\theta$ increases from $\alpha$ to $\beta$, then the length of $C$ is $$L = \int^\beta_\alpha \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta = \int^\beta_\alpha dS$$

I understand how this formula was derived, but I am confused as to why

1. The curve must only be traversed once for this to be true - I'd think this only matters if you're making a distinction between *distance a particle travels* and *length of path*.
2. Why it is useful to substitute in $dS$, and why that substitution is dependent on the single-traverse condition - we'd already derived this formula before this particular substitution was introduced and the single-traverse condition wasn't mentioned until this point.

Thank you!

Comment: Integration is based on the principle that the total is the sum of its parts. How do you refer to a small distance along a curve? The value $dS$ is simply that. Your first bullet is a little confusing. The definition of $dS$ has nothing to do with how many times the curve is traversed and we are looking at the distance a particle travels along the curve, not straight-line distance from our starting point.

Comment: @JohnDouma yes, that's exactly what I mean - if a particle is travelling along a curve, if the parameterization traverses the curve multiple times, isn't the particle traversing the curve multiple times, and therefore the length measured should include those multiple traversings? (E.g., in the very simple case of a parameterized circle, if the parameterizations are such that the circle is traversed twice, a particle travelling that circle might go around twice. Why do we need to specify that the circle only be traversed once?) As for $dS$, I understand what it means, just not *why* it's used.

Comment: (By which I mean, the longer formula involving the square root means the same thing, but describes exactly how we calculate a small distance along a curve. $dS$ does not.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider if $C$ passes a bit multiple times. Then the actual length of the curve would not increase, but the integral does. Thus we need to assume that the curve is traversed exactly once. The notation $\int_C dS = \int_C 1\,dS$ is not really a Substitution, but rather the definition of the curve integral. Basically this says that the length of the curve is the integral of $1$ over the curve (similar to how the volume of a $n$-dimensional set is the integral of $1$ over that set).

The single-traverse condition is not related to the definition of the integral, it’s just (as I already said) there as the length of the curve should only depend on its trace, and thus not increase by traversing it multiple times.

Comment: I'm not really asking about $\int_C dS = \int_C 1 dS$, but more about the full equation (with the square root of the squares) being swapped out for $dS$. I understand how the full equation is derived; I don't understand why we are notating this whole thing as $dS$ - it seems more obscure than just saying what it is. Thank you for the answer to the first question!

Comment: Why should we not? It is true that if you have absolutely no idea what $\int_C f\,dS$ is, you won’t understand it, but then if you do not know what $\int_a^b f\,dx$ is you will not understand the middle integral. But the notation $\int_C 1\,dS$ is much simpler to read and confirms that $\int_C f\,dS$ behaves the way we’d expect it to.

Comment: I mean, if you say what things are you’d need to write $\int_a^b\sqrt{(dx/dt)^2 + (dy/st)^2}$ as $$\lim_{\delta\to0,\, a=x_0<x_1<\ldots<x_n=b,\, x_i-x_{i-1}<\delta,\,\xi\in[x_{i-1},x_i]} \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(\lim_{h\to 0} (x(\xi_i+h)-x(\xi))/h)^2 + (\lim_{h\to 0} (y(\xi_i+h)-y(\xi))/h)^2}(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ as long as result exists and is the same for all possible choices.

And that is without saying what the $\lim$ is.